# Setup a http server to update the data every minute

Tags: python, http

I want to build a http server to broadcast the temperature  and update every 1 minute. I used microhttpd in C, now I want to write in Python. Which module should I use?

Hope to have your suggestions.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with the [http server module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) which would be perfect for something like this.

You could get started with this [tutorial](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2015/06/03/create-a-simple-http-server-with-python-3/) - I just looked it up so I haven't read it closely but it looks like it would cover most of what you need.